# How do I change the amount of time a player can spend underwater before taking drowning damage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to be able to give the player less air bubbles, or just make them drown a lot faster. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use /data set to set the Air tag of the player to a lower value, this will give them less remaining time to breathe.